# How to get value of the hidden cell?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I use gridView in my project.

I have this class:

```
public class FeatureDesc
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Tip { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

I create:

```
List<FeatureDesc> list_fd = new List<FeatureDesc>();
```

At some point I fill list_fd and set it as data source:

```
gvFeatList.DataSource = list_fd;
gvFeatList.DataBind();
```

Evrething is displayed(Title, Tip, ID) and works perfect.

But I need to hide ID column from user and at some point when I click row to get ID of the clicked row by
javascript function.

So my question is how to get hidden column text?

Comment: for that specific (`ID`) column set css style `display:none;`... is that help? you can always access value(s) of that column from JS (for example set `onclick="JSFunc(this);"` in every row, and so on... store `ID` in some `input type="hidden"` field after every row click).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a column is hidden in code behind it does not exist in html. But you can hide it using CSS and get the value on a row click

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFeatList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemType="YourNameSpace.YourClass.FeatureDesc">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <%# Item.Title %>

                //in a span element
                <span style="display:none;"><%# Item.ID %></span>

                //or a hidden field
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Item.ID %>' />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tip">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <%# Item.Tip %>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%= gvFeatList.ClientID %> tr").click(function () {
        var IDcontainer = $(this).find("span");
        alert(IDcontainer.html());
    });

    $("#<%= gvFeatList.ClientID %> tr").click(function () {
        var IDcontainer = $(this).find("input[type=hidden]");
        alert(IDcontainer.val());
    });
</script>
```

In this example I put the ID in a `<span>` element. But it could be a HiddenField, another colum etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting Visible property to false in markup or in code

Css  will do the trick:

Add css class to `<asp:boundfield>` like

```
   <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden-col"  DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID"/>
```

and then hide the class in css

```
 .hidden-col{
            display:none;
        }
```

This way ID value will be available for your js function.

Comment: Thanks for post.I get error when I put BoundFiels:

  <asp:GridView ID="gvFeatList" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover pointer height-10">
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" DataField="UID" HeaderText="UID" />
  </asp:GridView>

Comment: Try this <asp:GridView ID="gvFeatList" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover pointer height-10"> <Columns><asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" DataField="UID" HeaderText="UID" /> </Columns></asp:GridView>   Boundfield should be inside "Columns" tag

Answer (score 0):

One of the way you can bind the hidden column like

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="btnTitle" type="button" onclick='getId(this);' value='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                                    <input id="hdnfldID" type="hidden" value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                                    <br />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

and you can get ID by javascript like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getId(ele) {
        alert("Title : " + ele.value + "\n\rId : " + $(ele).closest('tr').find('#hdnfldID').val());
    }
</script>
```